# Blender and Active Stereo Display (3D Vision or similar)

Tags: opengl, stereoscopy

I am new to Blender.  I am drawn to it because of 1) its drawing capability and 2) its supposed support of stereoscopic display.

I have an "Nvidia 3D Vision" system that works under either Windows 10 or Ubuntu. 3D Vision is an "active" stereoscopic system aka OpenGL Quad Buffer Stereo, requiring the correct GPU, monitor, and viewing equipment (shutter glasses.)  Does Blender now, or did it ever, offer this display (not rendering) option?  I'm led to believe that it does (did), but I can't get it to work.  I know my OS, driver, hardware are not at fault because there are a few applications, notably sView (displays stereo pair still images and stereo video files) that work perfectly.

Nvidia discontinued the system about four years ago; it's more accurate to say the system is deprecated, as its Quadro Linux drivers still support it (actually three versions of it.)  I know it's a niche interest but I'm very confounded at the way the tech industry has walked away from stereoscopic imaging. A majority of the info on the web is VERY outdated, vague, or oriented to GeForce cards.  It's a tad less deprecated under Linux, as stereo support is retained in the driver itself, whereas under Windows support is "decoupled", requiring an auxiliary program (provided for free by Nvidia, as are the drivers.)

I'm SURE I read some years back Blender supported 3D Vision or other active stereo (there is at least one other system.)  ACTIVE STEREO is presumably equivalent to the "time sequential" stereo option described in the Blender.org manual Stereoscopy section.  I've got everything I need but the option doesn't show up on any of three Blender editions I've tried on Linux.  I can't even get the anaglyphic (red-blue) stereo mode to kick in.  (Several stereo modes are supported by the driver, but I only have equipment for anaglyph and "consumer" 3D Vision.)

Somehow Blender isn't detecting the time sequential option, either because said option does not exist or something else (command line argument?) is missing.  I've dug around the forum and I haven't seen this exact question; puzzling, because 3D Vision was widely marketed to gamers.  I'd think there'd be some of them out there!

3D Vision uses a 120hz display system; the glasses are controlled by IR or RF, depending on the version.  There was an anaglyph 3D Vision "Discover" system too, but I'm really interested in the active systems.  Ironically, active stereo seems like an easy trick for the GPUs that were built to do it.  Mine is a Quadro K4200.

I'm avoiding setting up a "2010-ish" system (Windows 7, old drivers, etc.)  Running an unsupported OS always leads to problems.  My goal is a reasonably modern system in terms of software and PC hardware; the viewing hardware will eventually fail but hopefully by then something new will be available.  I'll accept a limited choice of applications but now I'm on a quest to find them.  I hope Blender is one!